# Loading drop down values for angularJS

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am trying to load the drop down values from an array using angular js.

I see and can make it work when data (array is in this format);

```
items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Foo' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Bar' }
```

which can be loaded

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" 
            ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"></select>

</div>
```

However data I am receiving is in this format with no identifiers;

```
items = {["Moe", "Larry", "Curly"]}
```

How would i load the select with the names from my array?

Comment: Are you sure this is the right format of your data? Does it has curly braces before the square nes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll be looking for `item as item for item in items` as silly as that looks haha.

So;

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
<select ng-model="selectedItem" 
        ng-options="item as item for item in items"></select>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!